# C# and WebApi stream result of task collection

Tags: c#

I have a simple API and one service. Service is reading tree structure from path from configuration. problem is tree can be rather large, so I thought I can solve this by creating collection of tasks and resolve that tasks in form of stream on ActionResult. To make things harder I need a tree as result, can not split it to different requests.

So normally I would get file tree by:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles()
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var resource in _root)
    {
        this.ValidateRootFolder(resource);
        result.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(resource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    }
    return result;
}
```

So that is simple but can be slow if there is a giant tree, and what I am trying to do is something like:

```
public ConcurrentBag<Task<IEnumerable<string>>> GetFiles()
{
    var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task<IEnumerable<string>>>();
    Parallel.ForEach(_root, (resource, token) =>
    {
        this.ValidateRootFolder(resource);
        var task = Task.Run(() => Directory.EnumerateFiles(resource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        tasks.Add(task);
    });
    return tasks;
}
```

And this is creating task collection, so I can execute those that on endpoint, something like:

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("GetFiles")]
public IActionResult GetFiles()
{
    ConcurrentBag<Task> tasks = _fileService.GetFiles();
    return Ok(tasks); // how to make stream out of all these files
}
```

So my question is how to convert this task collection as stream with result, or is it possible?
And if not is there other way to do this?

Comment: "So my question is how to convert this task collection as stream with result, or is it possible? And if not is there other way to do this?" -> you want to return a list of Stream from each file name in `tasks`?

Comment: Parallelism in a web application is *not* a great idea because it uses threads that would be serving web requests otherwise. `Parallel.ForEach` will use all available cores, which means no other request will be served until either `Parallel.ForEach` completes or one of the worker threads is rescheduled

Comment: BTW `Task.Run` isn't useful inside `Parallel.ForEach` as the code is already running on a separate worker thread.

Comment: Besides, what do you want the results to look like? A flat list of paths? Or a list of lists?

Comment: What is the actual requirement? Explain the business problem, not how you think the solution would look like. Perhaps you need a protocol with true streaming, like gRPC, SignalR or WebSockets. If you don't care about ordering, multiple `Task.Run`s that feed their result to a Channel or gRPC server stream could be used to iterate in parallel *and* stream the results

Answer (score 0):

Parallelism in a web application isn't always a great idea because it uses threads that would be serving web requests otherwise. Each web request is served by a separate thread. If all cores are busy, web request will have to wait.

`Parallel.ForEach` will use all available cores, which means no other request will be served until either Parallel.ForEach completes or one of the worker threads is rescheduled. In most web applications that would be very bad.

One way to handle this would be to use PLINQ to enumerate all folders with a limited degree-of-parallelism and return the results as a single list:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles()
{
    var files= _roots.AsParallel()    
                    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
                    .SelectMany(fld=>Directory.EnumerateFiles(fld))
                    .AsEnumerable();
    return files;
}
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles()
{
    var files= _roots.AsParallel()    
                    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
                    .SelectMany(fld=>Directory.EnumerateFiles(fld))
                    .ToList();
    return files;
}
```

The benefit over `Parallel.ForEach` is that PLINQ handles the collection of the partial results into the final result set.

If you want to get the files grouped by root, you could use `Select` and `GetFiles` :

```
public IEnumerable<string[]> GetFiles()
{
    var files= _roots.AsParallel()    
                    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
                    .Select(fld=>Directory.GetFiles(fld))
                    .ToList();
}
```

You could also return a dictionary of files per root:

```
public Dictionary<string,string[]> GetFiles()
{
    var files= _roots.AsParallel()    
                    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
                    .Select(root=>(root,files=Directory.GetFiles(fld)))
                    .ToDictionary(p=>p.root,p=>p.files);
}
```

**No async**

There's no `Directory.EnumerateFilesAsync` so there's no way to benefit from *asynchronous* (not parallel) enumeration. The reason is that not all OSs have async IO and even when they do, *the file system drivers* may not have asynchronous file enumeration.

Windows NT was asynchronous from the start, with blocking operations emulated at the API level. Windows 9x wasn't. Linux on the other hand was synchronous, with async I/O added later. Even Windows doesn't have an async directory enumeration API though, because not all file systems support this.

Comment: Yea I thought so, I am bashing my head against the wall, but yet I had hope.

Comment: Hope for what? You can already iterate files in parallel. You can return the results as they're produced with an `IEnumerable`. There's no reason to return a task collection to do either.

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz if you want to make ASP.NET Core write the results directly to the output you could use `IAsyncEnumerable` as the return type instead of `IEnumerable`. You can write your own async iterator or use `ToAsyncEnumerable` from the `System.Linq.Async` package

Comment: Another possibility would be to use a protocol with real streaming, like SignalR or gRPC. Whatever you do you can't avoid the fact that HTTP can't stream messages. You may be able to write to the HTTP response without buffering but the *client* will still have to receive the entire response. Both SignalR and gRPC ASP.NET Core services allow you to stream data to a client, even use an infinite stream.